# jquery.browser in a library using jQuery1.9

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-migrate

This is a code snippet from datatables Colvis which is generating error. Works fine with jQuery1.8 or so....But complaining with jQuery1.9

```
if ( jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version == "6.0" )
{
    that._fnDrawCallback();
}
```

## error

TypeError: jQuery.browser is undefined

What could be the replacement or do I need to downgrade my jQuery..I saw jquery migrations as well, but was not much helpful.

Comment: ya browser property has been removed, you should test for feature support using: $.support http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Comment: Either downgrade jquery, update the datatables thing you are using to a newer version that supports newer versions of jQuery, or include the jQuery migrate plugin. While you're going to 1.9, you might aswell go to 1.10

Answer (score 0):

Basically it was not a solution, but although I just need to run the code, I used some dirty trick....although I could have simply pass the if condition...

```
        // if ( jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version == "6.0" )
        if ( jQuery.support.boxModel )
        {
            that._fnDrawCallback();
        }
```